# HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] vs [ScaffoldColumn(false)]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

What is Exaclty `ScaffoldColumn(false)` and `HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)`?

And What are the main difference between these two ? Which one is best to  use??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

`[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` tells Visual Studio not to scaffold the column when generating a template for your view. When you create a new view, you can create a strongly typed view. When you do that Visual Studio asks you what template to use (Create, Edit, List, etc). If you create an Edit/Create template; for example,  if you put `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` on your model property then it just won't generate a DisplayFor() or EditorFor() call in the template, so it won't be included in your view.

`[HiddenInput]` will tell the DisplayFor/EditorFor methods that it should create a hidden html field for that value. When you post to a form, it will be included in the values but it will be "hidden" from the view when people look at it.