# why my input returning validation error exception in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I'm new in MVC 4 and I want to create an application with validation 
one of My classes is:

```
public partial class Division
{
    public Division()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
        this.DevisionContnets = new HashSet<DevisionContnet>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DevisionContnet> DevisionContnets { get; set; }


    public virtual DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.Guid> InsertUid { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.Guid> UpdateUid { get; set; }
      public string UpdateStatment { get; set; }}
```

I don't want to user to see insert or update properties , I's for monitoring only!
when I delete those from scaffold views it getting me an error Indicatce to inner exception that datetime 2 out of range for an example of what I've done on edit OR Create view:

```
        <fieldset>
    <legend>Division</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

so why I'm getting an error and my object return the date to 01/01/0001?

Comment: It is better to use ViewModel with containing fields that user going to insert or update and at time of save assign that user filed data to your class with Guid and InsertDate.

Comment: should I create a ViewModel to every class I'll made? I's not a solution when I have 40 table in my current project and I have some simple classes like division how about the complicated ones?

Comment: It's good design to make Data contract between your entity class and DTOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you deleted your referenced fields and prevent the controller to get that data from those fields!
to hide your input fields just add annotations to your entity class:

```
    public partial class Division
{
    public Division()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
        this.DevisionContnets = new HashSet<DevisionContnet>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Grade Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DevisionContnet> DevisionContnets { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] // this will hide your data fields
    public virtual DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> InsertUid { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> UpdateUid { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string UpdateStatment { get; set; }

}
```

and keep your fields in your views with removing the scaffolded  labels

**Update:**
Alsow It's recommended to use ViewModel as recommended in Question Comments

Using [ScaffoldColumn(false)] can do the same but these values will not been generated so you'll not able to use those fields if you want to use them, So you have the options!

Answer (score 1):

For Making your properties not avaliable while scaffolding you can do it as follows:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public virtual DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdateDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: what the diff between [ScaffoldColumn(false)] and  [HiddenInput] ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085003/hiddeninputdisplayvalue-false-vs-scaffoldcolumnfalse

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54db21/scaffoldcolumnbool-value-vs-hiddeninputdisplayvalue-boo/

Comment: [ScaffoldColumn(false)] prevent mvc to generate those filed [HiddenInput will create them but as "hidden" fileds

Answer (score 0):

To hide a property from the UI via Data Annotations, decorate the property with

[ScaffoldColumn(false)] 
and they will be ignored by the editor templates.